# Returning Focus/Selection to Selected Cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I've been working on my DataError Handling on several different datagridvews in a few VB and C# projects.

These DataGridViews are bound from a table generated from a database, handle user input, and write them back to a database.  If the users enter valid data, all is wonderful, but if they try something like changing the primary key to a string, the errors are plentiful.

What I have that works well, but not perfect is:

```
Private Sub ChemicalsDataGridViewErrorHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles ChemicalsDataGridView.DataError
    e.Cancel = True
    ChemicalsDataGridView.EditingControl.Text = Nothing
    Call FillChemicalsDataGrid()  'goes back to the DB and just reloads the last valid table, writing back to DB at cell change
    Call ErrorLogWriter(e)
End Sub
```

This works, and clears the offending problem and get's the person back to a usable datagridview.  But it also put's the cell selection back at (0,0).  Is there a way I can use `DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress` to select the offending cell when the datagridview is reloaded?

I know I can breakdown to row and column like so:

```
Private Sub ChemicalsDataGridViewErrorHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles ChemicalsDataGridView.DataError
    e.Cancel = True
    ChemicalsDataGridView.EditingControl.Text = Nothing
    Dim cRowInt As Int32 = ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim cColumnInt As Int32 = ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    Call FillChemicalsDataGrid()  
    ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCell = ChemicalsDataGridView(cRowInt, cColumnInt)
    Call ErrorLogWriter(e)
End Sub
```

But it seems clunky to call for the row and the column separately (as someone who's never taken a programming class, I'm working on getting leaner code).  Especially when I can call DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.  I tried:

```
Private Sub ChemicalsDataGridViewErrorHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles ChemicalsDataGridView.DataError
    e.Cancel = True
    ChemicalsDataGridView.EditingControl.Text = Nothing
    Dim cCellLocation As Object = ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress
    Call FillChemicalsDataGrid()  
    ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCell = ChemicalsDataGridView(cCellLocation)
    Call ErrorLogWriter(e)
End Sub
```

But of course that wasn't enough arguments.

I also have been able to write the handler as a generic sub that is called, but I still haven't figured out how to have it called whenever there's an error in anyone of the different datagridviews.  Is there a way to catch any DatagridView.DataError across forms in one place?

Comment: I've not read your question to the end but `reloading a DataGridView` whenever user types in `invalid input` is not a good idea.

Comment: @KingKing You know I took it out and I don't think it's needed at all for the code to work.  I used it because it was in an example given to me.  I thought it would help prevent future errors.

Comment: IF you want one line: Use Dim cCellLocation As Point = ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress and then ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCell = ChemicalsDataGridView.Rows(cCellLocation.Y).Cells(cCellLocation.x)

Comment: @KreepN that's the awnser! Thanks. Here's the way I shortened it: `Dim cCellLocation As Object = ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress and then ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCell = ChemicalsDataGridView(cCellLocation.X, cCellLocation.Y)` ... I couldn't use Point, but late binding worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going to move my comment to an answer since it helped you out:

```
Private Sub ChemicalsDataGridViewErrorHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles ChemicalsDataGridView.DataError
    e.Cancel = True
    ChemicalsDataGridView.EditingControl.Text = Nothing
    Dim cCellLocation As Object = ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress
    Call FillChemicalsDataGrid()  
    ChemicalsDataGridView.CurrentCell = ChemicalsDataGridView.Rows(cCellLocation.Y).Cells(cCellLocation.x) 
    Call ErrorLogWriter(e)
End Sub
```

To answer the other question regarding a single place to handle errors, you would need to add event handlers in your app and have them all point to a single method:

```
AddHandler MyBuChemicalsDataGridViewtton.DataError, AddressOf DGVDataError
AddHandler OtherDGV.DataError, AddressOf DGVDataError
```

---

```
private Sub DGVDataError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs)

''dynamicly do things here for each DGV error

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the full response.  IDK if anyone else finds it cleaner, but I prefer `NamedDGV(LocationVar.X, LocationVar.Y)` to `NamedDGV.Rows(LocationVar.Y).Cells(LocationVar.X)`.  Still, clearly I wasn't understanding DGV.CurrentCellAddress.  Thanks again.